# How to make program only accept integer value from user input

Tags: c#, user-input

I have created code that returns the amount of days in a month to the console and I was wondering if there is a way that  I can verify if user input is an integer and if it isn't an integer it returns a message saying "error user input must be an integer"

This is currently the Code I have Created:

```
 using System;

 public static class GlobalMembers
{
 static int Main()
 {

    {


        Console.Write("Enter a Date to obtain how many days are in a month:");
        Console.Write("\n");
        int year = 0;
        int month = 0;
        int days = 0;
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) 
            Console.Write("Enter Year: ");
        year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.Write("Enter Month Number: ");
        month = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        if (month == 4 )
        {

             Console.Write("there are 30 days in the month April");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        if (month == 6)
        {
            Console.Write("there are 30 days in the month June");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }

        if (month == 9)
        {
            Console.Write("there are 30 days in the month September");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


        if (month == 11)
        {
            Console.Write("there are 30 days in the month November");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        if (month == 1)
        {
            Console.Write("there are 31 days in the month January");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


        if (month == 3)
        {
            Console.Write("there are 31 days in the month March");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


        if (month == 5)
        {
            Console.Write("there are 31 days in the month May");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


        if (month == 7)
        {

            Console.Write("there are 31 days in the month july");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        if (month == 8)
        {
            days = 31;
            Console.Write("there are 31 days in the month August");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


        if (month == 10)
        {
            days = 31;
            Console.Write("there are 31 days in the month October");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


        if (month == 12)
        {

            Console.Write("there are 31 days in the month December");
                            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        if (month < 1 || month > 12)

        {
            Console.Write("Error month range should be between 1-12");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        else if (month == 2)
        {
            bool leapyear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);

            if (leapyear == false)
            {
                days = 28;
                Console.Write("there are 28 days in the month Febuary");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            else
            {
                days = 29;
                Console.Write("there are 29 days in the month Febuary due to leap year");
                Console.ReadLine();



            }
        }

        else 
        {
            days = 31; 


        }



        return days;
        }
    }
 }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated thank you

Comment: Hint: instead of `Convert.ToInt32`, use `int.TryParse`, which stores the parsed value in an `out` parameter, and returns whether parsing was successful or not.

Comment: The [`Int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) documentation gives you pretty much exactly this as an example.

Comment: There is a built-in method for getting days in month: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmont

Comment: Luckily there are only 12 months in a year. Please read about the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle

Answer (score 1):

This still allows the user to input other characters, 
but it only accepts numbers:

```
bool correctInput = false;
while (!correctInput) // this loop will continue until the user enters a number
{
    Console.Write("Enter Year: ");
    correctInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out year); // if the parsing was successful it returns true

    if (!correctInput)
    {
        Console.Write("Your input was not a number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent user to enter a string or other characther with this code in textbox keypress event:

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
 e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
 }
```

Also you need to prevent shortcuts like ctrl+v because user can paste string to textbox. If you want to do this click textbox and go properties and change shortcuts property to disable.

Comment: This won't work for a console app which is what the question is about.